# Startup applications not working

Tags: 14.04, startup-applications

I have recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 and i want to add some extra applications to the start up process e.g. xpad, thunderbird and others, but i simply can not get it to work.
I have tried added programs using commands like "xpad" or by launching the executables but is did not work.

I am pretty sure i have done this the correct way but it just will not work.

Can you help me ?

Comment: Do the applications not start when you login? Please add what details you put into Startup Applications. Also, what desktop environment are you using?

Answer (score 1):

See this link :-

http://www.howtogeek.com/189995/how-to-manage-startup-applications-in-ubuntu-14.04/

It shows how to manage startup application in ubuntu.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score -1):

I realise that Startup Application does not like users
to check or uncheck more than 1 item for it to work properly.

I have now successfully use Startup Application
to start a program, execute command shell.

```
sh /path/tofile/xxx.sh
```

- Use Startup Application
- Create a new application to startup Teamviewer
- Reboot
- Goto Startup Application
- Create a new command execution to run `sh /path/tofile/srt-03.sh`
- Use a name say "run totem"
- Reboot
- Goto Startup Application
- Create a new command execution to run `sh /path/tofile/srt-03t.sh`
- Use a name say "xclose Teamviewer window"
- Reboot

Example of shell script

```
#!/bin/sh

cd ./

cd /path/to-file

/usr/bin/totem --fullscreen --play file:///home/path-to/file/playlist.m3u

exit 0
```

Comment: Dont forget to change to command shell script file to be executable! 
example
chmod a+x+w filename.sh